# Is there a way to pass a F# method to a Python function?

Tags: python, c#, .net, f#, python.net

I am trying to call a python function from F#. So far, I managed to call a simple Python function (e.g: to print a string). The problem is that I can't manage to pass a F# method to my Python function and call it from here.

Program.fs

```
let printMsg () = Console.WriteLine "Print from F#"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("PATH", pythonPath + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable "PATH")
    PythonEngine.Initialize ()

    let import = PythonEngine.ImportModule "HelloWorld"
    let helloWorld = import?HelloWorld()

    helloWorld?exec(printMsg)

    PythonEngine.Shutdown ()

    0
```

Helloworld.py

```
class HelloWorld:
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__")

    def exec(self, printMsg):
        printMsg()
```

But I get `Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'TypeError : object is not callable'` on the `helloWorld?exec(printMsg)` line of `Program.fs`, caused by the call to `printMsg()` from Python.

Comment: Why the "C#" tag?

Comment: Any solution that would work for C# would be compatible with F# and so fits my need. Also, I think that it's more likely to have C# dev having experienced python.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct a delegate from your F# function, then pass it to Python. I think `System.Action(printMsg)` should suffice.